# Laravel save tmp files

Tags: laravel, database, tmp

I changed the image upload directory to the public folder, but why is the file uploaded to the database on the tmp path? I want the record name in the database to match the file name. Can anyone help?

**Controller (store method)**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'banner_title' => 'required|max:255',
        'image' => 'image|file|max:5120',
    ]);

    $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
    $request->image->move(public_path('images/banner-image'), $imageName);

    Banner::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('/dashboard/banner')->with('msg', 'Success!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution,

- Add below statement before the **Banner::create($validatedData);**

> $validatedData['image'] = $imageName;

- In here we can assign validated image to $imageName after that we can save it in database.